# Display fetched base currency then convert to USD value and display on custom meta-box

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have fetched the value of _order_total_base_currency (from Aelia Currency Switcher) which is already converting in AUD. Having this value I want it converted into USD and display on my custom meta-box.

The code I have right now is doing just that, but by having a fixed multiplier of 0.79 (since 1 AUD = 0.79 USD).

What I like to do however is replace the "0.79" to a variable value that is an updated exchange rate perhaps coming from Google API?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cdmb_add_meta_box');
function cdmb_add_meta_box( $post_id ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom',
        __('USD Currency display','wc-usd-display'),
        'cdmb_display_meta_box',
        'shop_order',
        'side',
        'core'
    );
}

// The metabox content
function cdmb_display_meta_box() {
    // Get
    global $post;

        $total_usd = (get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true )) * 0.79;
        $total_usd .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true );
   ?>    
     <table id="wc_cdmb_display_meta_box">

            <tr>
            <th><strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Order Total Base Currency', 'wc-usd-display' ) ?> : </strong></th>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( ( empty( $total_usd ) ) ? __( 'N/A', 'wc-usd-display' ) : number_format(floatval($total_usd), 2) ); ?></td>
            </tr>

    </table>
<?php
}
```

[image: Custom meta box USD display]

The third party plugin Aelia Currency Switcher is outside of this. I already got what I want from it which is the value of _order_total_base_currency. Use the value as source to convert it to USD.

I'll appreciate all your help.

Comment: is not possible to use `apply_filters('wc_aelia_cs_convert', $amount, $from_currency, $to_currency);` in your code. instead you need some public functions that you can get only in the code of the plugin itself, As this is a commercial plugin and there is not any available developer documentation, you get very small chances to get helped.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have modified the question & attached an image just to be clear with what I like to do. The commercial plugin is already outside of this as I already got the source that I wanted from it. I just need a currency converter from outside source like Google API, to take the place of the fixed exchange rate of 0.79 in my code with real time exchange rate. Thanks in advance for your help.